# how to let @ExceptionHandlers handle specific exceptions before defaulting to an Exception handler for any Runtime error?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, exception

I want to use an @ExceptionHandler to handle any Hibernate exceptions. If the exception is not a Hibernate exception, then an @ExceptionHandler for Runtime errors handles the exception.

the problem is, Runtime exception is always taking precedence over the Hibernate exception handler. meaning, any hibernate exception that occurs is being handled by the general Runtime exception handler instead.

How can I ensure that Hibernate exceptions are handled by its exception handler, rather than being handled by Runtime exceptions?

```
    '@ExceptionHandler(HibernateException.class)
public String handleHibernateException(HibernateException exc, Model theModel) {

    String message = "An error has occured: " + exc.getLocalizedMessage() + "\n" + exc.getCause().toString()
            + "\r\n";

    myLogger.warning(message);

    theModel.addAttribute("exception", message);

    return "testing";
}

// handle any other runtime/unchecked exception and log it

@ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
public String handleRuntimeExceptions(RuntimeException exc, Model theModel) {

    String message = "An error has occured: " + exc.getLocalizedMessage() + "\n" + exc.getCause().toString()
            + "\r\n";
    myLogger.warning(message);

    theModel.addAttribute("exception", message);

    return "testing";
}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do checking if the exception is an instance of HibernateException by following way:

```
@ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
public String handleRuntimeExceptions(RuntimeException exc, Model theModel) {
    if (exc instanceof HibernateException) {
        return handleHibernateException((HibernateException) exc.getCause(), theModel);
    } else if (exc.getCause() instanceof HibernateException) {
        HibernateException hibernateException = (HibernateException) exc.getCause();
        return handleHibernateException(hibernateException, theModel);
    }
    String message = "An error has occurred: " + exc.getLocalizedMessage() + "\n" + exc.getCause().toString() + "\r\n";
    myLogger.warning(message);
    theModel.addAttribute("exception", message);
    return "testing";
}
```